# how to use sapply to split data frame and then do correlation between two variables in R

Tags: r, split, sapply

I have a data frame with an ID variable, and multiple rows per ID.

I want to split the data frame by ID, apply the `cor` function to variables x and y, then combine results in a vector.

I can find syntax for using `sapply`, splitting the data frame and passing the function one variable, but not two.

Here is syntax that isn't working:

```
answer <- sapply(split(df, df$ID), x=df$age, y=df$income, FUN=cor)
```

Here is a dummy data set:

```
ID  Age Income
1   20   20000 
1   30   30000
1   40   50000
2   25   30000
2   35   40000
2   40   60000
```

Anyone know the proper syntax for `sapply`, or another way to solve this problem?

Many thanks

Comment: `sapply(split(df, df$ID), function(x) cor(x = x$Age, y = x$Income))` or `by(df, df$ID, function(x) cor(x = x$Age, y = x$Income))`

Comment: `Map(cor, tapply(df$Age,df$ID,function(x)x), tapply(df$Income,df$ID,function(x)x))`